# Error: package file has a bad manifest

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

I searched for an answer to my problem, but I couldn't find a solution that worked.

I just created my first android app and when I try to install it from the app store, I get a message saying "Package file has a bad manifest."  I was hoping someone could point out what I did wrong and maybe even give a simple explanation for why it isn't working.

By the way, if I install the apk directly on my phone it does work, it just doesn't work from the play store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.coffeeBrewing.quadratic"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:logo="@drawable/icon" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.quadratric.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coffeeBrewing.quadratic) to the app.

Thanks to anyone that helps, I appreciate any and all tips.

Comment: does ur device version matches to manifest?

Comment: Where is your `MainActivity`? In which package?

Comment: my main activity is in the src folder.  I don't think it's in any package.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the one you just downloaded and Re-download it.I think the file got corrupted, because your manisfest.xml looks fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once. What I did is restart my Eclipse, then resign .apk and upload new version to the Play Market.

Also I noticed in your code that you Activity has different package name.

Try to change this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.quadratric.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
```

to this

```
<activity
    android:name="com.coffeeBrewing.quadratic.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
```